# modal windows over homepage instead of loading new page

Tags: jquery, windows, overlay, modal-dialog

new to jquery, and going for some mighty challenging things right off the bat.

i'm creating a portfolio website where the homepage contains images as links.

when the user clicks on the links, instead of load to a new page,
i would simply like a transparent overlay to occur, so that you can still see the content of the new page laid over the homepage. the user can get back to the homepage if they click on any area that isn't content from that page (over the homepage areas).

the image links on the homepage should also have hover states, which i know can be done using jquery fade in/out.

the effects can be found here at this site:
[example](http://www.studio-output.com)

not knowing where to start, i found some nice jquery modal window tutorials, but they can not handle images.

then of course, you have the jquery lightbox style slideshows, which overlay, but i don't want the slideshow.

i simply want the ability overlay a page's content over the home / current page.

any advice on how to attack this would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the dialog() widget if the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

We usually go with [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) as it allows for slideshows, HTML, AJAX content, IFrame content and videos as well.